# JavaFX BarChart doesn't display double or float values(only int,long and short)

Tags: java, javafx, bar-chart

I generated a BarChart in JavaFx using code(without SceneBuilder) and it fails to display double values on NumberAxis.I tried with int,long and short values and it works fine, but for some reason I cannot configure it to work with real numbers.

Here is my code:

```
private BarChart<String, Number> createBarChartMedii(Map<Student, Double> studentAndAverageGrades) {
    CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("Student");
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    yAxis.setLabel("Average");
    BarChart<String, Number> barChart = new BarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    barChart.setTitle("Grades Average");
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    studentAndAverageGrades.forEach((student, average) -> {
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(student.getNume(),average));
    });
    barChart.getData().addAll(series);
    return barChart;
}
```

This is the output:
[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrHgC.png)

If I modify the line which adds data into the series(inside the lambda function in foreach) with this one:

```
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(student.getNume(),average.intValue()));
```

it populates the BarChart

Comment: Cannot reproduce (the only thing I changed was converting the map to `Map<String, Double>` and replacing `student.getNume()` accordingly)... Are you sure you correcly fill the map???

Comment: There are plenty examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/scatter-chart.htm) of them using values with decimals.

Comment: Did you try using BigDecimal instead of Double? Can you check all the values of averages in case theres any outlier?

Comment: I just checked one error source that came to mind and it results in the behavior you observed: "non-numerical" values in the series, i.e. you likely have one of the following values stored in the map: `Double.NaN`, `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`. Probably this is caused by the way you fill the map (such as dividing by zero, if there are no grades for a student). BTW: `new Double(Double.NaN).intValue()` results in `0` which could explain the "correct" display when using `intValue()`; `Double.NaN` is the result of `0d/0d`

Comment: Thank you @fabian. That was the problem.I have one value which is DoubleNaN in my map and that's why it fails to read it.